# I want to loop this format using python

Tags: python, loops, nested

I have 3 lists

```py
a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = ["13", "14"]
```

and
the format is:

```
1 3 a

2 13 b

3 13 c

4 14 a

5 14 b

6 14 c
```

How do I get the above format?

Comment: You first need to clearly describe how the 3 lists turn into that format. What are the rules?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You need to be more specific, how should the data be represented, is it an array? or just the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to get the list `b` to cycle round and have an adapter with `itertools.repeat` to get `c` to repeat its items:

```py
from itertools import repeat, cycle

def repeat_elements(iterable, repeat_count):
    for element in cycle(iterable):
        yield from repeat(element, repeat_count)

a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = ["13", "14"] 

for x,y,z in zip(a, cycle(b), repeat_elements(c, 3)):
    print(x,z,y)
```

Output as requested

Note that this code relies on `zip` stopping the iteration when `a` has run out of elements. Both `cycle` and the adapter `repeat_elements` are going to loop endlessly.

Answer (score -1):

Below Code will print the required sequence with all characters in new line.

```
for i in c:
    for j in b:
        for k in a:
            print(k,i,j,sep='\n')
```

Comment: That does not produce the desired output